# Property of $\mathcal{A}$ set of closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I have proved the following statement and I would like to know if I have made any mistakes, thank you:

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a set of closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\bigcap_{F\in\mathcal{A}}F=\emptyset$. Prove that if $\mathcal{A}$ contains at least one bounded set then there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ and $F_1,\dots,F_n\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $F_1\cap\dots\cap F_n=\emptyset$

My proof:

Denote the closed and bounded set in $\mathcal{A}$ by $F_{cb}$. By taking complements we have that the set $\mathcal{A^c}:=\{F^c:F\in \mathcal{A}\}$ is a set of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, $\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal{A}}F^c=\mathbb{R}$ so $\mathcal{A^c}$ is surely an open cover of $F_{cb}$ hence by Heine-Borel Theorem $F_{cb}$ must have a finite subcover $F_1^c,\dots,F_m^c,\ m\geq 1$. $\ F_{cb}\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{m}F_i^c$ so $\bigcap_{i=1}^{m}F_i\subset F_{cb}^c$ thus $F_1\cap\dots\cap F_m\cap F_{cb}=\emptyset$ and since $F_1,\dots, F_m, F_{cb}$ are all closed, by setting $n:=m+1\geq 1$ and $F_{n}:=F_{cb}$ we have the claim.

Comment: I don't see any mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine, as Kavi already noted. If you'd know more about compactness and the FIP: suppose not, then $F \cap F_{cb}, F \in \mathcal{A}$ would be a family of closed subsets of the compact $F_{cb}$ with the FIP with empty intersection, contradiction.

Comment: thank you for your interest in my question; what does "FIP" stand for?

Comment: @lorenzo the finite intersection property